# Is there a django admin widget for adding multiple foreign keys with an inline through_model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a basic many to many relationship of:

Song to Playlist with PlaylistMember as the through model

Now I am displaying the songs in the playlist detail view using an inline View that is a subclass of TabularInline:

```
class PlaylistMemberInline(TabularInline):
    model = PlaylistMember
    raw_id_fields = ('Sound',)


class PlaylistAdmin(TranslatableAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = [PlaylistMemberInline]
```

[image: What I see in the admin]

To add multiple sounds I have to click on "Add another Sound", and then find that sound on a popup. This is annoying in my case, as I can find all sounds I want to add, but then have to click one and go back to "Add another Sound".

Is there a widget where I can search for, select and then add multiple Objects?

Comment: There is no standard widget in Django that will do this as part of the Django admin. Maybe some third party add ons may.

Comment: django-grappelli provides an autocomplete feature that you should manually take care of in the case of inlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django source code ([1.8 branch here, line 254](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py)) suggests that you can add your ForeignKey to radio_fields or raw_id_fields, resulting in a different widget.

In this case, add the field name "Sound" to `PlaylistMemberInline.raw_id_fields`, 
consider adding it to `PlaylistMemberInline.radio_fields`.